# How to get ko.observable() value

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to process a ko.observable with a global function. Here is my viewModel:

```
function articleVM() {
this.Id = ko.observable();
this.Title = ko.observable();
this.Status = ko.observable();
this.Url = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    return Admin.Global.removeDiacritics(this.Title);
}, this);}
```

where removeDiacritics is calling the .replace method on "Title".

So "Title" is an observable, and "removeDiacritics" is waiting for a string. How can I get the Title value and pass it to the function?

Comment: As it is right now your observable has no value attached to it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that inner scope "this" (the one used inside ko.pureComputed) is not the same as outer scope "this." You need to define your function a bit different:

```
function articleVM() {
   var self = this;
   self.Id = ko.observable();
   self.Title = ko.observable('SomeTitle');
   self.Status = ko.observable();
   self.Url = ko.pureComputed(function () {
      return Admin.Global.removeDiacritics(self.Title());
   }, this);
   return self;
}
```

Now self refers to the outer scope function. Also I gave the title observable "SomeTitle" value. I think this will fix your problem but if not I suggest you use jsfiddle and some console.log statements to figure out what values are assigned and where...

Comment: Thank you, "this" was the problem :) I forgot to mention that I had to make a little modification: "return SzmAdmin.Global.removeDiacritics(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self.Title));"

Answer (score 0):

Set title to an empty string

```
this.Title = ko.observable('');
```

and add the parentesis to title:

```
return Admin.Global.removeDiacritics(this.Title());
```